# Javascript: Getting alert to work in an external JS file

Tags: javascript, html, alert

My alert works perfectly fine with the other code removed but ceased to work after implementing everything else. Everything works with the exception of the alert function. Could someone please help me?

HTML File

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>Red Text, Verdana Font, Alert</title>
</head>
<body>
<p id = "my1"></p>
<p id = "my2"></p>
<p id = "my3"></p>
<script src ="kappa.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript File

```
alert("Coding with JavaScript");

var my1 = document.getElementById("my1");
my1.innerHTML = "Red Text";
var my2 = document.getElementById("my2");
my2.innerHTML = "Vardana Font";
var my3 = document.getElementById("my3");
my3.innerHTML = "Alert";

document.getElementById("my1").style.color = "#ff0000";
document.getElementById("my2").style.color = "#ff0000";
document.getElementById("my3").style.color = "#ff0000";

document.getElementById("my1").style.fontFamily = "verdana";
document.getElementById("my2").style.fontFamily = "verdana";
document.getElementById("my3").style.fontFamily = "verdana";
```

Answer (score 3):

I put both files in a same folder. test.html and kappa.js, when I visited test.html, your alert and other code worked. I suggest you check your javascript console for any lingering errors that might of caused this issue.

[image: working1]

[image: working2]